# Binary tree with zigzag pattern

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How can you arrange a sequence of n distinct numbers such that if inserted one at a time into a binary search tree, it generates a tree of height n - 1 following a zig-zag pattern such as left, right, left, right, …

I just need to determine what property the sequence would have to have, rather than actually building an algorithm that would produce the sequence.

Comment: Won't you get that if each new value alternates between being greater than the previous and also smaller than the one before that (if one exists), or smaller than the previous and also greater than the previous one before that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's work out an example. The first value we insert into the tree can be anything, so I'll pick 0.

```
 0
```

Now, we need something where we take a step to the right. That means I need something bigger than 0, so I'll pick 137.

```
 0
  \
  137
```

Now, I need something that will be a left child of 137. That means it must be between 0 and 137 - anything smaller goes to the left of zero, and anything bigger goes to the right of 137. So, I'll pick something in that range, say, 42:

```
  0
   \
   137
   /
  42
```

Now, I need something that becomes the right child of 42. That means that it has to be between 42 and 137. Anything smaller would go to the left of 42 (or the left of 0, equally not okay) or to the right of 137 (not okay either). So let's pick something between 42 and 137 - say, 98:

```
  0
   \
   137
   /
  42
   \
   98
```

You might notice a pattern here: at each point, **the value we insert must be between the last two values inserted**. Do you see why this is? Based on that, can you think of a way of ordering the values 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 so that you get a zigzag pattern?

Hope this helps!